# Alternate templates not showing up in the template dropdown

Tags: web, shopify, liquid

I have a page.special.liquid (alternate template) under templates folder in my theme file. However when I go to  'Add Page', Select a template option, this template is not showing up. What is going wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the theme currently published in your store?

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs when you are working in the non published theme.
To solve this problem Create a template of same name  in the currently active(published) theme. Then it will list in the non active theme's admin.

Comment: that didnt work for me. i had to publish the theme

Answer (score 3):

If you are not working on the currently published theme, make sure you have an alternative template with the same name (in your case page.special.liquid) in the active theme.